# TypeScript - Pass Dynamic Property Name to Children

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm working on a routing library with nested routing where I'm trying to define a child handler function which infers the parent paths. The reason being is I have another type which can infer dynamic path parameters from a string (e.g., `users/:id` to `{ id: string }`); so, I want to be able to pass down the inferred path parameters from parent routes to any and all child routes in each child's route handler function.

Here's what I have so far:

```
type RawRouterDefn<Namespace extends string = ""> = {
    [K: string]: Handler<Namespace, typeof K> | RawRouterDefn<`${Namespace}/${typeof K}`>;
};

type Handler<DataPath extends string, Path extends string> = ((args: { dataPath: DataPath, path: Path }) => unknown)

type Router<Routes extends RawRouterDefn, DataPath extends string = ""> = {
    [K in keyof Routes & string]: Routes[K] extends CallableFunction
        ? Handler<DataPath, K>
        : Router<Routes[K], `${DataPath}/${K}`>;
};

function createRouter<T extends RawRouterDefn>(rawDefn: T): Router<T, ""> {
    // Implementation not important right now
    return {} as unknown as Router<T, "">
}

const router = createRouter({
    some: {
        deeply: {
            nested: {
                /**
                 * Here, dataPath should be inferred as `some/deeply/nested`,
                 * path should be `route`
                 */
                route: ({ dataPath, path }) => {}
            },
        },
    },
});

const route = router.some.deeply.nested.route;
// Correctly inferred **after** function applied, I need it within the router definition
type Params = Parameters<typeof route>[0]
```

(And the [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASghgdxgewK7AgJwCIQGYB2APAHJwC2EAzmHAMbQQAeGBAJlVFcJgJYEBzKAF4oAIjEA%20EVADeAKACQAbQDSALi49%20AgLqaAEnHYAbLKQrVaDADRRQkZHiirpAH1iIU6LLkJEAAwASWTJKGnoIAF8AehCHCCcXKIDJAG55KIz5BKgjU3NsOGA4AAVigAsoZlYOLT5BO3LgKpqIdk5uBoFpUQAKPrhMASpNWSg2YrLKzSKS5oq7WhbNBagogEoRaVQCAGsCZAQCDfkc8GhvDEwiK%20pqlna6%20CQ0a78COznplofazu0ghkEl6ciUaig-CgewgICSd04ADJ6jp9LA3tQ1Lo-k9OABhOAmExwABGZgAYrs6MBeMgCEpFAB%20PLGNhmG7fBZ2VwMzR3G4IrF2YKyTmVWIhVQpdKZbJ4Kk0ulQOiYCDFCD8ogAFRxHU8rx8OHwBEkfUwiA%20mi1Gz5GJuWrsILBUCgMRiUAAkuQwGZKAQSoqCFBDsBId7kJgSv6oHwBBVQ4dUFQIPIXargKhMEHZFEoHBOLsDkcg-n0YbtY6pJkznQ6dwY3aZCq1Rh%20X0FIoqMhKGMGWwIBAfSBe4pRwRqBg2L2XTOZzEAFTz1Oz2fzvJYCB2SbzSpcCpoExsKAk6D8PBYVVH0sBLuUGL9wcmEAxcfcCBsAI2Zcrl1r5ZVKh91QQ9j2gAJMAxAJvx-ecYgZUcIJ8TR2wmKYuSgf91i2YRpBzeCoi-UcCKUYjNmyWsCHrRCMBkaisAAOlvCB6IfId6NfSd6LojI3SgPEI1Vakn0hAhz0wS8oEXOA8GuRcoHlAhqVpEswB9Xh3zsD1gwHI9eFDBA9IqKEWmgOjMAmfB%20D05TzkgKBynNchOFEBzLGuKgiASJI6MkZQAAZdCAA) to the playground)

I'm almost there, except `dataPath` should be inferred as `/some/deeply/nested` and not `/${string}/${string}/${string}` and `path` should be inferred as `/route` and not `/${string}`. This suggests to me there's something I'm missing in the `RawRouterDefn` type.

So it seems that I can correctly narrow the shape of the string, but no further with my current approach.

Again, I need it to be inferred when used as function arguments, not after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite close, just needed to do a little magic with the generics:

```
function createRouter<T extends RawRouterDefn, R extends Router<T, "">>(rawDefn: R): R {
```

And now it works: https://tsplay.dev/NDRE1W

You need another generic to tell TypeScript that what you get in the function is exactly what you return. Removing `T extends RawRouterDefn` and using `R extends Router<RawRouterDefn, "">` breaks the inference, so uh, don't do it.