# Combine Inferences from Mapped Type and Generic Function

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, type-inference

Taking my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73805290/typescript-pass-dynamic-property-name-to-children/73805501#73805501) further, I'm trying to combine inference on a mapped type with inference from a generic function call all n the same object property. I want the `dataPath` attribute to be inferred from the property names of the object, whereas the `Context` type is inferred from a type argument passed into the `Builder` type below:

```
type BaseType<Context, DataPath extends string> = (ctx: { data: Context, dataPath: DataPath}) => unknown

type Join<Root extends string, Leaf extends string> = Root extends '' ? Leaf : Leaf extends '' ? '' : `${Root}.${Leaf}`

type RecursiveTree<Context, Namespace extends string = ''> = {
    [K in string]: RecursiveTree<Context, Join<Namespace, K>> | BaseType<Context, Join<Namespace, K>>
}

type Builder<Context, Ns extends string = ''> = {
    /* I want this to be a function
    * Join<Ns, TreeName> should then, somehow, be used as the Ns
    * type argument to Builder so "leaf" gets the updated namespace
    */
    tree: <TreeName extends string, Tree extends RecursiveTree<Context, Join<Ns, TreeName>>>(tree: Tree) => Tree

    // I do not want this to be a function preferrably
    leaf: {
        // ...Some other (optional_ chainable methods until we reach create
        create(handler: BaseType<Context, Ns>): BaseType<Context, Ns>
    }
}

const builder = {} as Builder<{ foo: string }>

// In all cases below, I still want to infer the Context object as well
const defn = builder.tree({
    // ctx.dataPath here should be inferred as "innerLeaf"
    innerLeaf: builder.leaf.create((ctx) => {}),
    innerTree: builder.tree({
        // ctx.dataPath here should be inferred as "innerTree.innerLeaf"
        innerLeaf: builder.leaf.create((ctx) => {}),
        innerInnerTree: builder.tree({
            // ctx.dataPath here should be inferred as "innerTree.innerInnerTree.innerLeaf"
            innerLeaf: builder.leaf.create((ctx) => {})
        })
    })
    // And so on ...
})
```

Now, if I defined the tree manually, the shape of the data path would be inferred (bringing me to the same problem as in my last question):

```
const tree: RecursiveTree<{ foo: string }> = {
    innerLeaf: (ctx) => "",
    innerTree: {
        innerLeaf: (ctx) => "",
        innerInnerTree: {
            innerLeaf: (ctx) => "",
        }
    }
}
```

But, I want consumers to use a `Builder` object, not manual definition as it will provide other forms of inference that would require manual typing otherwise.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Here's a [link](https://tsplay.dev/m0nqPw) to the playground

Comment: In your playground you have a comment over `leaf: { ... }` that says "I do not want this to be a function preferably". What would you prefer then? Is this even needed to address the problem?

Comment: I'm 99% certain that the API you are asking for is not possible to represent. Currently, there is no way to tell the compiler that the inner call to `builder.tree` (in the `innerTree` property) is related to the root call of `builder.tree`. That's why I don't believe you can "pass" on the namespace to the child calls.

Comment: With my (possibly wrong) comments about the desired result out of the way, [here is my take](https://tsplay.dev/mZXYaw) on how you *could* do it otherwise. See that in all the functions, `ctx.dataPath` *is correctly inferred*, but this does not use any of your `builder.tree` or `builder.leaf.create` methods inside. Is it **necessary** for those to be used, or can you workaround this in your real implementation?

Comment: @caTS Thanks for attempt. Unfortunately, the builder methods are the actual API, I just wished to pass down the data path as an enhancement.

Comment: @caTS I tried to modify your example a little and made some discoveries: https://tsplay.dev/mMBA1W